# how to select fields in related tables quickly in django models

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to get all values in current table, and also get some fields in related tables.

```
class school(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    school_type = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    school_address = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class hometown(models.Model):
    hometown_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class person(models.Model):
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    person_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    person_school = models.ForeignKey(school, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person_ht = models.ForeignKey(hometown, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

how to quick select all info i needed into a dict for rendering.
there will be many records in person, i got school_id input, and want to get all person in this school, and also want these person's hometown_name shown.

i tried like this, can get the info i wanted. And any other quick way to do it?

```
m=person.objects.filter(person_school_id=1)
.values('id', 'person_name', 'person_id', 
school_name=F('person_school__school_name'), 
school_address=F('person_school__school_address'), 
hometown_name=F('person_ht__hometown_name'))
```

> person_name, person_id, school_name, school_address, hometown_name

if the person have many fields, it will be a hard work for list all values.

what i mean, is there any queryset can join related tables' fields together, which no need to list fields in values. 
Maybe like this:

```
m=person.objects.filter(person_school_id=1).XXXX.values()
```

it can show all values in school, and all values in hometown together with person's values in m, and i can

```
for x in m: 
   print(x.school_name, x.hometown_name, x.person_name)
```

Comment: `select_related`, `prefetch_related`.

Comment: can you give me a example? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You add a `prefetch_related` query on top of your queryset.

`prefetch_data = Prefetch('person_set, hometown_set, school_set', queryset=m)`

Where `prefetch_data` will prepare your DB to fetch related tables and `m` is your original filtered query (so add this below your `Person.objects.filter(...` )

Then you do the actual query to the DB:

`query = query.prefetch_related(prefetch_data)`

Where query will be the actual resulting query with a list of `Person` objects (so add that line below the `prefetch_data` one).

Example:

```
m=person.objects.filter(person_school_id=1)
.values('id', 'person_name', 'person_id', 
school_name=F('person_school__school_name'), 
school_address=F('person_school__school_address'), 
hometown_name=F('person_ht__hometown_name'))

prefetch_data = Prefetch('person_set, hometown_set, school_set', queryset=m)

query = query.prefetch_related(prefetch_data)
```

In that example I've broken down the queries into more manageable pieces, but you can do the whole thing in one big line too (less manageable to read though):

```
m=person.objects.filter(person_school_id=1)
.values('id', 'person_name', 'person_id', 
school_name=F('person_school__school_name'), 
school_address=F('person_school__school_address'), 
hometown_name=F('person_ht__hometown_name')).prefetch_related('person, hometown, school')
```

Comment: what i mean, is there any queryset can join related tables' fields together, which no need to list fields in values. Maybe like this: m=person.objects.filter(person_school_id=1).values().XXXX it can show all values in school, and all values in hometown together with person's values in m, and i can "for x in m: print(x.school_name)"